# Moving around a div randomly, and continuously on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div move around using jQuery -

I did refer to few examples on stackoverflow, which talks about setTimeout(), which I made use of, in the above code.

**Issue:**
I was expecting the little div to play around at random locations on screen 100 times, however, the result was completely different. I just got the final position of the div rendered on the screen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var playing = false;
  var top;
  var left;
  var i;

  // the button controls the play start/stop, based on "playing"    
  $('.play').click(function() {
    if (!playing) {
      // if not playing, start playing around 10 times...
      playing = true;
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
          left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
          $('.random').offset({
            top: top,
            left: left
          });
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      // if playing, stop the play and return to 0,0...
      playing = false;
      top = left = 0;
      $('.random').offset({
        top: top,
        left: left
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.random {
  background-color: black;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="random"></div>
<button class="play">Click Me!"</button>
```

Comment: Your timeout is `1000` for each iteration. You would probably have to do something like `(100 * i)` for your timeout

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/1aqa1amx/

Comment: Works like a charm, though I didn't quite understand the 100 * i part. And another thing I observed is that the button is stuck during the iteration. Does it have to wait for the iteration to complete?